# solidity declarationerror identifier not found or not unique for voting

Tags: blockchain

I have this code for a voting system but when I compile it give me error in here ( boolean if_voted; )
can any one help me please. 
thank you

this is the code :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract Ballot {
    struct Voter {
        uint weight;
        boolean if_voted;
        address delegated_to;
        uint vote;
    }
    struct Proposal {
        bytes32 name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    address public chairperson;
    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;
    Proposal[] public proposals;
    constructor(bytes32[] memory proposalNames) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;

        for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
            proposals.push(Proposal({
                name: proposalNames[i],
                voteCount: 0
            }));
        }
    }
    function giveRightToVote(address voter) public {
        require(
            msg.sender == chairperson,
            "Only the chairperson can assign voting rights."
        );
        require(
            !voters[voter].voted,
            "The voter has used their ballot."
        );
        require(voters[voter].weight == 0);
        voters[voter].weight = 1;
    }
    function delegate(address to) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(!sender.voted, "You have already voted.");

        require(to != msg.sender, "You can’t delegate to yourself.");

        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0)) {
            to = voters[to].delegate;
            require(to != msg.sender, "Found loop in delegation!");
        }
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;
        Voter storage delegate_ = voters[to];
        if (delegate_.voted) {
            proposals[delegate_.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
        } else {
            delegate_.weight += sender.weight;
        }
    }
    function vote(uint proposal) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(sender.weight != 0, "Cannot vote");
        require(!sender.voted, "Has voted.");
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = proposal;
        proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }
    function winningProposal() public view
            returns (uint winningProposal_)
    {
        uint winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
            if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
                winningProposal_ = p;
            }
        }
    }

    function winnerName() public view
            returns (bytes32 winnerName_)
    {
        winnerName_ = proposals[winningProposal()].name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
boolean if_voted;
address delegated_to;
```

To this:

```
bool voted;
address delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        bool if_voted;
```

try using 'bool' instead of 'boolean

you should declare your struct 'Voter' as shown below,

```
    struct Voter 
{ 
    uint weight;
    bool voted;
    address delegate;
    uint vote;
}
```

Comment: I fix it as you said then it gave me this error : member "voted" not found or not visible

Comment: your variable 'voted' is not declared inside your struct, rename it as 'voted'.